# Make the entire content scrollable with a fixed footer of variable height

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a fixed footer in my application. 
When content gets bigger than the height of the screen, it adds a scroll bar to it. But I am not able to see the end of the content because it lies just below the footer and the footer being fixed doesnt let me scroll over it or see it.
 
**Please note : Height of the footer is actually not known and I have other fixed divs that get created above the footer runtime. So the content should be scrollable over all the fixed divs in the bottom.**

JS fiddle for the same : https://jsfiddle.net/wfck8y8n/

The following code in the fiddle gets hidden because of the fixed footer.

```
<div>I might get hidden because of footer</div>
```

How to make this visible using just CSS?

Comment: Add padding to the bottom of your content that is the same height (or greater) as the fixed footer.

Comment: Add `padding-bottom: 20vh;` (same as footer height) to `body`

Comment: Add padding-bottom to the content, so the footer overlaps only the padding.

Comment: Thanks.I tried that and it did work. But the problem is that the height of the footer div is not fixed. And in my application I have few other fixed divs that get created runtime above the footer.

Comment: If `height` is unknown; in my opinion; you will need to use some JavaScript.

Comment: Wrap `#footer` and `#content` in `#wrapper`. Add `padding-bottom` on `#wrapper` equal to `height` of `#footer` when page loads.

Comment: Yes Javascript is like my last resort.But I am trying to implement it using CSS

Comment: You don't need JS. But you need a different strategy than `position:fixed` on the footer. For example, you could divide your page using flexbox. E.g. https://jsfiddle.net/wfck8y8n/2/

Comment: @Alohci : Thanks a lot. I will try using flex in my application for footer.

Comment: @Alohci : Can you please post your comment as answer to help others?

Answer (score 0):

Put all content into the content wrapper and define the height as 80vh (since the footer is 20vh).

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
}

.content {
  height: 80vh;
}

.content div {
  min-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>I might get hidden because of footer</div>
  <div>I might get hidden because of footer</div>
  <div>I might get hidden because of footer</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  I am footer

</div>
```

Comment: Height of the footer is actually not known and I have other fixed divs that get created above the footer runtime.I will update the same in the question

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to push the footer as the content grows bigger :

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -20vh; /*the bottom margin = -(footer's height)*/
}
.push, #footer {
    height: 20vh;
}
#footer {
    position : fixed;
    bottom : 0;
    background-color : black;
    color : white;
    width : 100%;
}
.content div{
  min-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
  </div>
  <div>I might get hidden because of footer</div>
  <div>I might get hidden because of footer</div>
  <div>I might get hidden because of footer</div>

  <div class="push"></div>

</div>

<div id = "footer">
  I am footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add margin-bottom: 60vh property in body.

```
body{margin-bottom:60vh;}
```

So please refer below sample:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfck8y8n/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest way to achieve this might be by wrapping in a `div` all the sections except for the footer, and then add to that wrapper a  `margin-bottom` rule that equals in pixels the height of the footer.

I made a Codepen [demo](https://codepen.io/rogersegu/pen/ayWWZO), I hope it helps.